# Google Heat Map intensity based on value

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heatmap

I want to create a heat map using Google API (Javascript). The problem is that Heatmaps use colors to represent the density of points. But, in my case the density of points is irrelevant. I want to create a map using a specific set of values. The colors on the map will be determined by that value only for that location. My set of values is Latency (ms).

Example: If a value is low it will appear on the map with green color. If a value is high it will appear with red color.

I´ve searched the API documentation, but the only thing i found was using "weighted locations". This is not a suitable solution, because the density of points is still considered.

Comment: This guy seems to try to do the same thing and found a solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742074/heat-map-on-google-maps-based-on-the-intensity-of-a-parameter
Just something to look into http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/

Comment: @DasBeasto, before posting this question i saw that question and i've seen that website, but, still, the intensity is given by the density of points, adding the "weighted locations". I don't know how he resolved his problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JohnMurhy did you find the solution..?

Answer (score 0):

This is something the Google Maps JavaScript API currently does not provide out of the box.

To achieve this, you may use a visualization framework like [deck.gl](https://deck.gl), where heatmap aggregation may be set to [MEAN](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/aggregation-layers/heatmap-layer#aggregation).